# using return in get

Tags: c#

i have question about why should we use return in get,if dont use what happend?.plz see the code below:

```
private int _NumberOfDoors= 4;
public int NumberOfDoors
{
   get
   {
      return _NumberOfDoors;
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get` is just a method that returns a value, so you *have* to return a value.  If you don't your code won't compile!  You could of course have the `get` automatically implemented for you:

```
public int NumberOfDoors
{
   get;
}
```

This is a read-only property.

Comment: Small sidenote: get; is only available from .NET 3.0 and higher, if you use .NET 2.0 you'll have to write the complete implementation of the get method

Comment: You can't have automatically implemented readonly properties (unless marked as abstract), how would NumberOfDoors ever be set? I'm pretty sure this won't even compile.

Comment: @fletcher: Yes, you're right, you'd need a `private set` or `protected set` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using properties is a best practice to access your local variables. More info on properties (and get/set) can be found on [MSDN Properties article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

A small extract from there:
"The get keyword defines an accessor method in a property or indexer that retrieves the value of the property or the indexer element"
It retrieves the value, so you need to use the `return` keyword.

"The set keyword defines an accessor method in a property or indexer that assigns the value of the property or the indexer element."
Set assigns the value, so you'll use `varX = value;`